# Windows Forms TableLayoutPanel 2 Rows use all space

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

I want a TableLayoutPanel with 2 Rows. The second row is 200px high. The first row the rest. If resize, only the first row resizes.

How to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor the TLP to the bottom.  Click the tasks glyph (upper right corner), Edit rows and columns, Show = Rows, select the 2nd row and change the Size Type to Absolute.

Also note that you don't really need a TLP for this.  Just use a regular Panel and dock or anchor the controls to the bottom.